# Consider the following dice game, as played at a certain gambling Casino: Players 1 and 2 roll a pair of dice in turn.

Tags: conditional-probability, dice, covariance, gambling

Consider the following dice game, as played at a certain gambling Casino: Players 1 and 2 roll a pair of dice in turn. The bank then rolls the dice to determine the outcome according to the following rule: Player $i$, $i = 1,2$ wins if his roll is strictly greater than the banks. For $i = 1,2$, let

$${\cal I}_i = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & {\rm if} & i \; {\rm wins} \\ 0 & & {\rm otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

Show that ${\cal I}_1$ and ${\cal I}_2$ are positively correlated.

Answer: I understand that I have to show that cov(${\cal I}_1, {\cal I}_2) = E[{\cal I_1}{\cal I}_2] - E[{\cal I_1}]E[{\cal I_2}] > 0$. I understand how to find each expected value, however I am unaware of how to find the joint probability distribution for the situation. For example, how do I go about calculating $P({\cal I}_i)$, $P({\cal I}_1 = 1, {\cal I}_2 = 1)$, etc?

Comment: By "strictly greater" I assume you mean that if the bank rolls $(3,2)$ and player 1 rolls $(5,1)$ then player 1 wins because $6>5$ (rather than the bank winning because while $5>3$, he loses since $1 \leq 2$).

Comment: I don't understand - what if e.g. both players roll a $2$ and the bank rolls a $1$? Do they both win? Similarly, if both players roll a $1$ and the bank rolls a $2$, do they both lose?

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that the sum of the roll is "strictly greater".

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about the sum of the rolls...

Comment: Yes they can both win. As long as they beat the Bank.

Comment: Consider using the law of total probability and another random variable $B$ corresponding to the value of the bank's roll.  Assuming every player (*including bank*) is rolling a single die each, you have $Pr(I_1=1,I_2=1)= Pr(I_1=1,I_2=1\mid B=1)Pr(B=1)+Pr(I_1=1,I_2=1\mid B=2)Pr(B=2)+\dots+Pr(I_1=1,I_2=1\mid B=6)Pr(B=6)$.  Now... what is the probability that both players won if the bank rolled a $1$?  What is the probability that both players won if the bank rolled a $2$? ... What is the probability that both players won if the bank rolled a $6$?  What was probability the bank rolled a $1$? ...

Comment: Adjust in the case that you were talking about each player rolling two dice, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right up front, we can predict that these will be positively correlated because if you tell me that player $1$ has won, that says something about the bank number tending to be lower than its usual distribution, and that in turn increases the chances that player 2 will have won as well.  But that might be hand-waving; let's look at the joint distribution and the actual comparisons.

Note that the bank's number is among $\{12, 11, 10, \cdots , 2\}$ with probabilities $$\{\frac1{36}, \frac2{36}, \frac3{36}, \frac4{36}, \frac5{36}, \frac6{36}, \frac5{36}, \frac4{36}, \frac3{36}, \frac2{36}, \frac1{36}\}$$ and that the probability of each of the players rolling better than the bank will be 
$$
\left\{\frac{0}{36}, \frac{0+1}{36}, \frac{0+1+2}{36}, \cdots, \frac{0+1+2+3+4+5+6+5+4+3+2}{36} \right\}
$$

So the probability, for a given bank number ranging from $12$ down to $2$, of one specified player winning will be
$$\frac{1}{36}\left\{0 , 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 26, 30, 33, 35 \right\}
$$
and multiplying by the probability of each of those bank numbers we get:
$${\cal I}_1 = \frac{1}{36} \frac{1\cdot 0 + 2 \cdot 1 + 3 \cdot 3 + \cdots +6 \cdot 15 + 5\cdot 21 \cdots  + 2 \cdot 33 + 1 \cdot 35}{36}  = \frac{575}{1296}
$$

To find the joint probability distribution, it will suffice to find $P_{11}$, the probability of both players winning, and $P_{00}$, the probability of both players losing,
since pretty obviously $P_{10} = P_{01} = \frac{1-P_{11}-P_{00}}2$ and that covers all four possible joint outcomes.

To find $P_{11}$ we need the probability, for a given bank number ranging from $12$ down to $2$, of **both** players winning, which will be  will be
$$\frac{1}{36^2}\left\{0^2 , 1^2, 3^2, 6^2, 1^2, 10^2, 15^2, 21^2, 26^2, 30^2, 33^2, 35^2 \right\}
$$

Then multiplying by the probability for each bank number we get
$$P_{11} = \frac{1}{36}\frac{1\cdot 0^2 + 2 \cdot 1^2 + 3 \cdot 3^2 + \cdots +6 \cdot 15^2 + 5\cdot 21^2 \cdots  + 2 \cdot 33^2 + 1 \cdot 35^2}{36^2}  = \frac{13035}{46656}
$$

Similarly, to find $P_{00}$ we need the probability, for a given bank number ranging from $12$ down to $2$, of **neither** player winning, which will be  will be
$$P_{00} = \frac{1}{36}\frac{1\cdot 36^2 + 2 \cdot 35^2 + 3 \cdot 33^2 + \cdots +6 \cdot 21^2 + 5\cdot 15^2 \cdots  + 2 \cdot 3^2 + 1 \cdot 1^2}{36^2}  = \frac{18291}{46656}
$$
and from these we can calculate $$P_{10}=P_{01}= \frac{7665}{46656}$$

Finally, to answer your question, $E({\cal I}_1) = E({\cal I}_2) = \frac{575}{36^2}$
while $E({\cal I}_1 {\cal I}_2) = P_{11} = \frac{13035}{36^3}$.

$$
E({\cal I}_1 {\cal I}_2) = \frac{13035}{36^3} = \frac{469260}{36^4} >  \frac{330625}{36^4} = \left( \frac{575}{36^2} \right)^2 = E({\cal I}_1) E({\cal I}_2)
$$
so ${\cal I}_1$ and ${\cal I}_2$ are positively correlated.